# Setup golf ball physics

Tags: physics, 3d

I am developing a simple **Golf** game as shown in the below image.

[image]

I am facing below issues:

1. Even if I apply small amount of force, the ball continuous move along the grass? Grass friction is not stopping the ball.
2. Sometimes, the ball speed is increased after colliding with the walls instead the ball speed should decreased after collision with the walls. The walls are having box collider.
3. Sometimes, the ball reverses its direction after colliding with walls.

**Code:**

Physics properties of the **ball**:

```
 ball.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = true;
 ball.physicsBody.mass = 0.0450;
 ball.physicsBody.restitution = 0.8;
 ball.physicsBody.friction = 0.3;
 ball.physicsBody.allowsResting = true;
```

Physics properties of the **grass**:

```
golf.physicsBody.friction = 0.8;
```

Physics properties of the **walls**:

```
 leftWall.physicsBody.friction = 0;
 leftWall.physicsBody.restitution = 0.8;
```

I have set the physics world gravity value to -9.8.

I am looking for suggestions to fix the above listed issue. Thank you.

Comment: Isn't there a separate friction value for rolling?

Comment: Yes. But should I apply that value to ball or the grass surface?

Comment: apply it to the ball.

Comment: Even if I increase the rolling friction to 0.8, the ball continues to move along grass surface.